# creating AVERAGEIFS in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've never used `AVERGEIFS` before, and it's getting a little too complex for me, so please help me out.

I have a range, where I want to average column values in column A for rows that have column value B equal to 2 and column A values lesser than 3, so is this correct:

```
    WorksheetFunction.averageifs(columnA, columnA, "<3", columnB, "2")
```

**EDIT**
I get a "Type Mismatch"

ColumnA and ColumnB are ranges, in if sentences this is what I want

```
IF columnA < 3 AND columnB = 2 Then Average(columnA)
```

<strike>**Edit**</strike>

I'm assuming this must have something to do with my types then, the averageifs throws a `1004 cannot get the averageifs property of class worksheetfunction` when I enter my parameters, however countifs throws `13 Type Mismatch` given the same parameters:

```
For Each column In importsheet.UsedRange.Columns
    colcount = .CountIfs(column, column, "<3", importsheet.UsedRange.Columns(DepColumn), sec)
Next
```

DepColumn and colcount are integers,
sec is a string with an integer ("2")
clusterfuck of errors above, stroke it out

Comment: You tagged your question as ´excel-vba` - are you trying to access the AVERAGEIFS formula in VBA, i.e. using `WorksheetFunction.Averageifs` - or are your refering to normal Excel formulas?

Comment: @PeterAlbert Thank you for clarifying, I'm talking about worksheetfunctions.averageifs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your posted code is correct *provided*

- you have `Dim`'ed `columnA` and `columnB` as `Range`'s and `Set` then to valid ranges
- the data on your sheet returns a result (ie there is at least one row that meets the criteria)

Demo with error handling:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim columnA As Range
    Dim columnB As Range
    Dim v
    Set columnA = [A:A]
    Set columnB = [B:B]

    On Error Resume Next
    v = WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(columnA, columnA, "<3", columnB, "2")
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        'No matching data
        v = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I seem to have an error in every run, and the countifs returns a type mismatch, so I suspect it is something else than getting no results?

Comment: I suggest you create a stripped down test routine to try and reproduce the error, and post that

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `columnA` and `columnB` are ranges of the same size, your formula is correct:

```
WorksheetFunction.Averageifs(Range("A:A"),Range("A:A"),"<3",Range("B:B"),"2")
```

will return you the average of column A where A<3 and B=2.

Comment: thank you, I'm glad I got it right, except I didn't entirely, I'm still getting Type MisMatch errors, although to me the arguments look like the right types.